# Show that the equation $ $ $z^6-i=0$ $ $ is sufficient to define a polygon. Find the area of this polygon.

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, problem-solving, polygons

Show that the equation $ $ $z^6-i=0$ $ $ is sufficient to define a polygon.  Find the area of this polygon.

---

Would this problem make sense to the average 6th former? (that is, students of 17-18 years old, in their last secondary school year).

Comment: Shouldn't $z^6 - i = 0$ have *six* solutions? And what shape (or polygon as you put it) has *six* sides?

Comment: @user477343 we're not interested that much about the sides, but more about the vertices.  Are you saying the question is ambiguous or too straightforward?

Comment: No I was just giving a hint. I mean, if a shape has $n$ sides then it will by default have $n$ vertices. I guess I didn't want my hint to be too straightforward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No

> Show that the equation  $z^6-i=0$  is sufficient to define a polygon.

This is a rather meaningless sentence. We all know that the roots of this equation are the vertices of a regular hexagon in the complex plane and so we try to guess what you want to ask. But you didn't ask this.

So no, you should not use such a formulation.

Better say

> Show that the roots of $z^6−i=0$ are the vertices of a polygon in the complex plane.

Comment: Hum.  The question state to "show" what you just wrote.  That's what's being asked.  How do you know it's a regular hexagon?  Can you elaborate on how you'd improve the wording, please?

Comment: Stephen, am I right that you want to pose this question to your students?

Comment: Not "my" students, per se (I don't have students).  But to *some* students, yes.

Comment: "to be sufficient" has no mathematical meaning here.

Comment: So you'd say *"defines a polygon (or hexagon)"* $ $ $ $ instead of $ $ $ $  *"is sufficient to define a polygon"*?

Comment: I would say "the roots of $z^6-i=0$ are the vertices of a polygon in the complex plane".

Comment: That indeed sounds better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would. Consider the complex plane and the points defined by the 6 roots of the equation!

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Just making sure before I share it.

Comment: No, don't share it. Your post here isn't clear enough. Only from your comments it becomes clear that you want to pose this question. I think the other answers assume that someone posed this question to you

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The roots of equation $z^n=a$ are vertices of some figure for $|a|>0$.

Comment: Great. Glad to see that bit wasn't ambiguous.